# iterate through all the values of a key in hashtable java

Tags: java, loops, hashtable, key-value

```
Hashtable<Integer,String> ht = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
ht.put(1,"student1");
ht.put(1,"student2");
```

How can I iterate through all values of "a single key"?

`key:1 
 values: student1, student2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use:

```
Hashtable<Integer, List<String>> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, List<String>>();
```

and add the new String value for a particular key in the associated `List`.

Having said that, you should use a `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`. The later one is legacy class, which has been replaced long back by the former.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

then before inserting a new entry, check whether the key already exists, using [`Map#containsKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) method. If the key is already there, fetch the corresponding list, and then add new value to it. Else, put a new key-value pair.

```
if (map.containsKey(2)) {
    map.get(2).add("newValue");
} else {
    map.put(2, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("newValue")); 
}
```

---

Another option is to use [Guava's `Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), if you can use 3rd party library.

```
Multimap<Integer, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

myMultimap.put(1,"student1");
myMultimap.put(1,"student2");

Collection<String> values = myMultimap.get(1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What doea Arrays.asList("newValue") mean?

Comment: @sweet. It creates a new List with the values passed into the method. Go through the documentation of that method in `Arrays` class.

Answer (score 5):

A Hashtable doesn't store multiple values for a single key.

When you write ht.put(1, "student2"), it overwrites the value that goes with "1" and it is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks so what data structure should I use?

Comment: Hashtable<Integer, List<String>> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, List<String>>(); as @Rohit Jain pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hashtable doesn't allow multiple values for a key. When you add a second value to a key, you're replacing the original value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple values for a single key, consider using a HashTable of ArrayLists.